# How to duplicate one whole entry in SAP business one?

Tags: sapb1

How can i Duplicate the whole entry as new Entry with next auto number.For example if form contains Trading number(4) and trading details(a,b,c). Trading details(a,b,c) should duplicate with new trading number(5). I searched in forum and got only duplicate row.help me to overcome this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem with Duplicate menu enabling in right click event

```
  oForm.EnableMenu("1287", True)
```

this will give duplicate menu when "Right click". It will duplicate whole entry and creates new entry.I catch the menu event and manually increase the autoumber.